# es6 call class methods from within same class

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to call a class method in my class form a neighboring method as shown in the example below.

```
import blah from './blaha';

export default class myclass{
  constructor(con) {
    this.config = con;
  }

  async meth1(paramA) {
    //do_stuff...
  }

    meth2(paramB) {
     //attempt to call meth1()
  }

}
```

I would like to call a method from within a different method using es6 class styles.

Comment: Mainly I'm trying to pass some objects to a different method in the class to process some work on it.

Comment: One issue I keep seeing, is that I can not call a method if I am inside of a separate function in the other method

Comment: Like always: `this.meth1()`. *"I can not call a method if I am inside of a separate function in the other method"* Sounds like a duplicate of [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196) then.

Comment: I can't read this without thinking, "don't do meth"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `this`

```
import blah from './blaha';

export default class myclass{
  constructor(con) {
    this.config = con;
  }

  async meth1(paramA) {
    //do_stuff...
  }

  meth2(paramB) {
     this.meth1()
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a similar issue, with a subclass.  Can't call a neighboring method within a subclass unless it is declared in a parent class.

Comment: @kiwicomb123 that's how inheritance works. You should declare methods in parent class and use it in siblings.

Comment: I never mentioned anything about inheritance.  Not all methods of a subclass are relevant to their siblings.