# Calling method in JS class returns "...is not a function"

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, keydown

i have JS class that has method like this:

```
  setupComponent() {
    document.getElementById("message-input").addEventListener("keydown", this._onKeyPress);
    document.getElementById("send-button").addEventListener("click", this._onSend);
  }
```

Right under it, there are two methods:

```
  _onKeyPress(event) {
    if (event.code === "Enter") {
      this._onSend();
    }
  }

  _onSend() {  
     console.log("send");
  }
```

My question is: why direct call from "click" eventListener works (it logs message), and `this._onSend()` method, called in `_onKeyPress` returns `this._onSend is not a function`.

Also using `this._onSend()` inside `setupComponent()` works.

Is this some kind of magic associated with eventListeners?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: The magic is that "this" doesn't always mean what you think it means.

Comment: I thought this might be a problem, but why does it work here then:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43642729/calling-a-method-from-another-method-in-the-same-class

It looks very similar.

EDIT: also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785860/es6-call-class-methods-from-within-same-class/36248405

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function is used as an event handler, its this is set to the element the event fired from [this - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). So you cant expect your methods to be there, but you can bind your this to your function using `Function.prototype.bind()`.

```
document.getElementById("message-input")
      .addEventListener("keydown", this._onKeyPress.bind(this));
```